# Django can't find my static files after changing to production settings and back

Tags: python, django

I've been trying to deploy my site this weekend and have thus been meddling with the settings. One of the unpleasant surprises while doing this has been that my static files have seemingly stopped working on my site. My CSS files and javascript files don't work anymore, as if they aren't found by the site. The only thing I can remember doing with regards to static files was inserting this into settings.py:

```
# The absolute path to the directory where collectstatic will collect static files for deployment.
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

# The URL to use when referring to static files (where they will be served from)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I removed these settings and replaced them with the original

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

but alas, the problem remains. Why isn't Django finding my static files anymore?

PS: As I'm a noob, I don't know exactly what is relevant from my project for you guys to see, but do let me know and I shall provide additional info.

Comment: Have you ran python manage.py collectstatic ?

Comment: No. Should I change back to production settings and run it?

Comment: I'm also curious to know why it doesn't start working again when I change back the settings.

Comment: @AndréRoggeriCampos I changed back to my first settings example in the question, ran `collectstatic`, and it made static files work again. However, I still don't understand why I can't simply change back the settings and have them work like before. Does anyone know why?

Comment: How are you deploying ? Manually copying files and running migrations or do you have a automated deploy?

Comment: I'm using heroku, following this tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Deployment . I just changed the settings and it stopped working even though I changed back

Answer (score 0):

Okay, update your settings.py as below:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_my_proj"),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_cdn", "static_root")
```

Now, that you have done that make dir called `static_my_proj`, at the same level where your `manage.py` file is.

Okay, now create new dir called `static_cdn` just one level up, i.e. one level up to `manage.py` file.

Now, create dir called `static_root` inside `static_cdn` and that is all you have to do. Make sure you run `python manage.py collectstatic`

NOTE:

`static_my_proj` is for development or `DEBUG = True` and `static_cdn` is for production or `DEBUG = True`. handy, right?

Also, you can add media file the same way, just add,

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_cdn", "media_root")
```

and make new dir called `media_root` under `static_cdn`.

**EDIT:**

Copy all your `admin` files to static dir manually.

If you have virtualenv than go to `<virtualenv-dir>/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static` and copy dir named `admin`.

It should work even if `DEBUG=False`

Hope this helps.